# Передача значений в функцию

Tags: инспекция-кода, delphi-7

В процедуре объявляются переменные `tD1`, `tbetta`, и ничем в дальнейшем не инициализируются, но код работает. Вопрос - почему он работает?

```
Procedure MakeDO;
var te,tD1,tbetta:real;
    t,ti:integer;
begin
 AssignFile(FT_EXM,'REZ.TXT');
 Rewrite(FT_EXM);
  if ifsaveclasses then begin
   for ti:=1 to n do
     Write(FT_EXM,VD[ti],' ',ND[ti],chr(9));
   Writeln(FT_EXM);
 end;
 for k:=1 to m do begin
 if ifsaveclasses then begin
 AssignFile(FT,'REZ'+inttostr(k)+'.TXT');
 Rewrite(FT);
 SaveClass(k);
 end;
   em[k]:=0;
   em_NWS[k]:=0;
   d[k]:=0;
   MakeSK(k);
   for t:=0 to n do begin
     te:=INFK(t,tD1,tbetta);
      if ifsaveclasses then
      Writeln(FT,t,chr(9),te:0:5,chr(9),td1:0:3,chr(9),tbetta:0:3,chr(9),1-td1:0:3,chr(9),1-tbetta:0:3,chr(9),round(td1*nr),chr(9),round((1-td1)*nr),chr(9),round((1-tbetta)*nr),chr(9),round(tbetta*nr));
      if te>EM_NWS[k] then begin EM_NWS[k]:=te;d_NWS[k]:=t;d1_NWS[k]:=td1;b_NWS[k]:=tbetta; end;
      if (tD1>=0.5)and(tbetta<0.5)and(t<dc[k])then begin
      if te>em[k] then begin em[k]:=te;d[k]:=t;d1[k]:=td1;b[k]:=tbetta; end;
      end;
   end;
   if ifsaveclasses then begin
   Writeln(FT,'Class ',k,chr(9),'Em= ',em[k]:0:5,chr(9),'do= ',d[k],chr(9),'dc=',dc[k],chr(9),'D1= ',d1[k]:0:2,chr(9),'Betta= ',b[k]:0:2);
   Writeln('Class ',k,chr(9),'Em= ',em[k]:0:5,chr(9),'do= ',d[k],chr(9),'dc=',dc[k],chr(9),'D1= ',d1[k]:0:2,chr(9),'Betta= ',b[k]:0:2);
   Writeln(FT_EXM,k);
   for ti:=1 to n do
     Write(FT_EXM,EV[k,ti],' ');
   Writeln(FT_EXM);
   Writeln(FT_EXM,d[k]);
   closefile(FT);
   end;
 end;
    closefile(FT_EXM);
end;
```

Comment: Функция `INFK` вероятно выглядит так: `function INFK(t: integer, var tD1, tbetta: real): real;` или `out` вместо `var`. Второй и третий параметры передаются как ссылки, и их значения присваиваются внутри `INFK`.

Comment: @lgor function INFK(t_:integer;var t_D1:real; var t_betta:real):real;

Comment: @AndrewBystrov вопрос в том, какие значения передаются в функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `INFK` вероятно выглядит так:

```
function INFK(t: integer, var tD1, tbetta: real): real;
```

или `out` вместо `var`. Второй и третий параметры передаются как ссылки, и их значения присваиваются внутри `INFK`. После вызова

```
te := INFK(t, tD1, tbetta);
```

`tD1`, `tbetta` имеют значения присвоенные внутри `INFK`.